# Removing interaction factors

Tags: categorical-data, least-squares, lm

Should I remove non-significative factors even when their interactions are significative?

Consider the following R `lm` summary:

```
> summary(lm(QUOTA~PROMO1*CONCO1,dados51))

Call:
lm(formula = QUOTA ~ PROMO1 * CONCO1, data = dados51)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.153307 -0.051151 -0.007775  0.045731  0.202959 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    0.295497   0.006914  42.741   <2e-16 ***
PROMO1         0.015052   0.011975   1.257   0.2098    
CONCO1        -0.018971   0.009383  -2.022   0.0442 *  
PROMO1:CONCO1  0.041545   0.019361   2.146   0.0328 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.06774 on 278 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.06237,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05225 
F-statistic: 6.164 on 3 and 278 DF,  p-value: 0.0004535
```

Can I remove PROMO1?

I think I was told in my applied statistics course to never remove first-order effects when second-order effects are significative. But it would be great if someone could confirm this for me.

(Bonus points if you know literature on this. Thank you!)

Comment: Are you asking whether the model should be respecified as `QUOTA ~ CONCO1` (removing PROMO1 and its interaction), or as `QUOTA ~ CONCO1 + PROMO1:CONCO1` (removing a 'main effect' of PROMO1 but leaving in the interaction)?

Comment: (For the second question @jonas-berge's answer is correct; in the absence of nested factors it's a bad idea to leave an interaction without a main effect)

Comment: @conjugateprior the second question, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't remove the main terms if their interaction is significant because it makes the interpretation of the interaction term difficult, and I think it will also distort the estimated effect making it more unreliable. Two references:

Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R. Zuur and Ieno. 2009.

Modelling Survival Data in Medical Research, Third Edition. Collett. 2014.